# Can I split word by terms in Elasticsearch to improve performance on `wildcard`?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch6.8 and using `match_phrase_prefix` and `wildcard` in the query. I found the performance it quite bad. What I am thinking is to manually tokenize the text into an array of terms.

For example, the field has a text like `ABCD`, instead of doing prefix query or wildcard query, I split the text into an array `["A", "AB", "ABC", "ABCD"]` during index building. Then use `match` query on the field. So when users send a request like `AB`, it will performance an exact match. Is this a good solution for that? How does it impacts scoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you are suggesting is what the edge_ngram tokenizer does in elasticsearch.
This would increase your index space by producing a lot more tokens.
So it really depends on your usecase so if you have less data size then this would speed up the query response but a more common usecase for this is auto-suggest(search-as-you-type queries).
You can read more about it here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

Coming to the point of scoring : though it depends on what query you are firing but in general it wont have much difference when compared to the match_phrase_prefix as you would comparing same tokens.

Comment: I see that `edgengram` max_gram configuration can't be set to the length of the text. I have to specify a hard coded value for max_gram. Is there a way to set it as an unlimited value?

Comment: this tokenizer is generally used at index time, so you can set the max_gram to a value higher than you max word length(or any high value),you can read more about max_gram here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/max-gram-limits.html

Comment: I just found out that this tokenizer is only available on version 7. I am using 6.8 which doesn't have such feature.

Comment: it is a very old tokenizer and is available in the previous versions also, here is the official doc link for the version you are using : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html